# pino with pino-tee stops logging after a few 100 lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been unable to stream pino logging into pino-tee for more than 200ish to 400ish lines of the 1000 expected. The following `index.js` (ESM) demonstrates this neatly:

```
import childProcess from "child_process";
import fs from "fs-extra";
import stream from "stream";
import path from "path";
import pino from "pino";
import util from "util";
const setTimeoutPromise = util.promisify(setTimeout);

/**
 * MyLogger - fast, out-of-process logging with pino and pino-tee
 */

export class MyLogger {

    logger; // pino instance

    constructor({name, logsDir, toFile} = {}) { // name could be name of the program or whatever info
//debugger;
        this.logThrough = new stream.PassThrough();
        this.logger = pino({}, this.logThrough);    // send everything to file, including TRACE
        this.logger.level = "trace";

        // pino-tee's purpose is to log this.logger's output into a file, or into multiple
        // files in parallel, separated by level ('fatal', 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace' or 'silent')

        if (toFile) {

            const teePath = path.join(
                // process.cwd() can't work to get to node_modules folder in pkg because "internal" stuff (node_modules) lives at /snapshot/
                // so if running under pkg, use process.pkg.defaultEntrypoint and work our way up one file, one directory
                process.cwd(),
                "node_modules", "pino-tee", "tee.js"
            );

            const utc = MyLogger.toUTCFS(); // file-system friendly UTC datestamp string

console.log({teePath});

            const child = childProcess.spawn(process.execPath, [    // node command
                teePath,
                // https://dev.to/stephencweiss/what-is-require-resolve-and-how-does-it-work-1ho4
                //require.resolve('pino-tee'),  // pre-ES6 way of getting the executable path
                "trace", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "trace"}),   // not supported by pino-colada
                "debug", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "debug"}),   // not supported by pino-colada
                "info", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "info"}),
                "warn", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "warn"}),
                "error", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "error"}),
                "fatal", MyLogger.buildLogFilePath({logsDir, name, utc, subId: "fatal"}),
            ], {
//              cwd: process.cwd(),
                env: process.env
            });
            this.logThrough.pipe(child.stdin);  // now pipe ugly output to tee's stdin
        }
    }
    fatal()     { this.logger.fatal(...arguments);  }
    error()     { this.logger.error(...arguments);  }
    warn()      { this.logger.warn(...arguments);   }
    info()      { this.logger.info(...arguments);   }
    debug()     { this.logger.debug(...arguments);  }
    trace()     { this.logger.trace(...arguments);  }

    // Default convenience static method to log as INFO


    /**
     * log() - use instead of console.log
     */
    log() {

        // file output

        for (const arg of arguments)
            this.trace(arg);    // co-opt the trace level to not ouput anything to console

        // console.log() as normal

        return console.log(...arguments);   // instead output to console like this
    }

    /**
     * buildLogFilePath()
     * @param {string} param0.name
     * @param {string} param0.suffix defaults to ".jsonl", see https://jsonlines.org/
     * @returns
     */

     static buildLogFilePath({name, suffix = ".jsonl", utc = "", subId = "", sessionId = "", logsDir}) {
//console.log("============================================>", logsDir);
        if (!fs.existsSync(logsDir))
            fs.mkdirSync(logsDir, {recursive: true});
        utc = utc || MyLogger.toUTCFS();    // file-system friendly UTC datestamp string
        const s = path.parse(name).name // filename without extension
        + (subId ? ("-" + subId) : "")  // profile name
        + "-" + utc     // creation time of the current session;
        + suffix;

        // create logs in logs/*.log
        const outFilePath = path.join(logsDir, s);

    //console.log(MMHelper.ansiBgYellow + "logsDir =", logsDir,
    //"execFileName =", execFileName, "path.parse(execFileName).name =", path.parse(execFileName).name,
    //"sessionId =", sessionId, "utc =", utc, "utc =", utc, "suffix =", suffix, "s =", s, "outFilePath =", outFilePath);

        return outFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * toUTCFS() - make a filesystem-safe
     * @param {*} inDate
     * @returns
     */
    static toUTCFS(inDate) {
        if (typeof inDate === "number" || typeof inDate === "string")
            inDate = new Date(inDate);
        else if (!inDate)
            inDate = new Date();
        return inDate.toISOString().replace(/(\W+)/gi, "-");

    }

}


await main();

async function main() {
    const rootDir = process.cwd();
    let logName = process.argv[1];  // name of script
    const publicDir = path.join(rootDir, "public");
    const logsDir = path.join(publicDir, "logs");
    let toFile = true;
    let logger = new MyLogger({name: logName, logsDir, toFile});    // used by MMDebug.log() if present

console.log({name: logName, logsDir, toFile});

    for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        logger.log(`${i}: hello world`);

    console.log("BEGIN waiting 5 seconds...");
    await setTimeoutPromise(5000);
    console.log("END waiting 5 seconds...");
}
```

I am following the ESM examples at https://github.com/pinojs/pino-tee/pull/18/files#diff-98328e3b3ad8e1560c1bbe15b7e4de95e8724b7b542d64c0a752116dd8d8c973 closely but no luck beyond a few 100 lines.

I even wait at the end of the code (it hangs indefinitely anyway because it spawns a subprocess), but either there's a failure to flush buffers on pino's side, or pino-tee stops receiving and processing data.

Can anybody enlighten me? Note that I won't accept solutions that turn on synchronous writing, as that defeats the whole purpose of using pino.

The pino & pino-tee combination markets itself as the fastest damn NodeJS logging solution out there, exactly because of the asynchronous piping. Just that, in the example shown, it doesn't work past a few 100 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so this was just identified as a small omission in the pino / pino-tee examples -- need to insert `child.stdout.resume();` after `logThrough.pipe(child.stdin);` in the above code, like so:

```
this.logThrough.pipe(child.stdin);
child.stdout.resume();
```

Reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/42630

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same problem.